# SQL Server Express Connection String Error in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string, sql-server-express

I want to run a small C# program. Its database is on my local host in SQL Server. Now I want to change it to an SQL Server Express one. I have made a database which its name is exactly same with the one in local host, I have made the tables too.
Now I want to change the connection string. What syntax should I use?

I have used this one:

`Server = localhost\SQLEXPRESS; Database = MyStore_DB; Trusted_Connection = true`

I have used it in **MyStore.App.exe.config** and **MyStore.DataLayer.dll.config** files instead of the previous connection string in part **ConnectionStrings**.

But an error occurs. Could you please help me if I'm mistaken in any step?

error:
[the picture of the error occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG7bb.png)

Comment: Can you post the error message please.

Comment: All the examples you need are here https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/

Comment: Are you able to connect to the Sql Express database in SSMS and run a query against it using the connection string you provided above?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string it's wrong. Once you've declared **TrustedConnection=true** (you miss the ';' at the end) it means that you will login into the database using Windows Authentication.

Beyonds that, if you wanted to login with an specific user and password, you may try this:

> Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=YourDB;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Id=yourUser;Password=yourPassword;

Notice I'm using "." instead of localhost